# Create Bootable USB drive with "Press Any Key To Boot" Message

Tags: windows, command-line, usb, bootable-media

I'm trying to make a usb bootable trough command line. I can do it but there is a problem. I will boot automatically without any prompt! I need to see "Press Any Key To Boot..." first and decide to press any key to boot or not.

Is there any way to add this prompt to a bootable usb using command line?

Comment: You'll need to add a custom MBR that prompts with that message. What have you attempted already? Have you tried [using Rufus](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-add-press-any-key-to-boot-from-usb-to-bootable-windows-usb/) to do this yet?

Comment: Yes I used Rufus, But I need to do this from command line.

Comment: Not unless you can come up with a command-line utility that can create or modify the MBR. I know of no such software or method, so I'm out..  Good luck!

Comment: You can do this with [MagicIso](http://www.magiciso.com/)

Comment: MagicISo is commercial :( I have found an article here But I do not know if it can help, anyone could help please in this case? https://www.raymond.cc/blog/5-free-tools-to-backup-and-restore-master-boot-record-mbr/